# GCP Terraform Conditional on Public Address

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I have a module that creates a VM.  As a variable for the module, I would like to have a conditional that selects whether or not to add a public IP to a VM interface.

Here is my main.tf (trimmed down)

```
module "vm_egress" {
  source          = "./modules/create_vm/"
  vm_name         = "my-vm"
  vm_machine_type = "n1-standard-4"
  vm_zone         = "us-east-4a"
  vm_subnetwork   = "my-subnet"
  vm_private_ip   = "10.0.0.2"

  # Conditional for public IP on network.  If true, set access_config to {}.
  apply_public_ip = "true"
}
```

Here is my module (trimmed down)

```
resource "google_compute_instance" "vmseries" {
  name                      = "${var.vm_name}"
  machine_type              = "${var.vm_machine_type}"
  zone                      = "${var.vm_zone}"

  network_interface {
    subnetwork    = "${var.vm_subnetwork}"
    network_ip    = "${var.vm_private_ip"

    # Set access_config based on boolean of "apply_public_ip"
    access_config = {}
  }
}
```

Any help or direction on this would be much appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like there may have been similar puzzles in the past.  See:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/terraform-tool/yF7DeRynEZU/wgIRXQToBgAJ

Answer (score 0):

One alternative might be to create separate public and private subnets, and specify the subnet into which the VM is deployed via the conditional instead. This would accomplish the same thing, and avoid the clutter of having both public and private VMs in the same subnet.